# reshape 1d array to 3d for tensorflow.js lstm

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, lstm, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to predict future stock prices using time series data. I have an xs array of 251 timesteps, and a ys array of the corresponding stock price for that time step. I have reshaped the xs array to be 3d, but get an error

'Input Tensors should have the same number of samples as target Tensors. Found 1 input sample(s) and 251 target sample(s).'

the code for the model is below.

```
var xs = [];
var ys = [];
for(i in result){
    xs.push(i);
    ys.push(result[i].close);
    }

    var xt = tf.tensor3d(xs, [1,xs.length,1]);
    var yt = tf.tensor2d(ys, [xs.length, 1]);
    //xt.reshape([1, xs.length, 1]).print();
    //yt.reshape([1, ys.length, 1]).print();
    var lstm1 = tf.layers.lstm({units: 32, returnSequences: true, inputShape:[xs.length,1]});
    var model = tf.sequential();
    model.add(lstm1);
    model.add(tf.layers.dropout({rate:0.2}));
    model.add(tf.layers.lstm({units:5}));
    model.add(tf.layers.dropout({rate:0.2}));
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({units:1, inputShape:[32], activation:'softmax'}));
    model.compile({optimizer:'adam', loss:'categoricalCrossentropy'});



    model.fit(xt, yt, {epochs:1000}).then(() => {

  bestfit = model.predict(tf.tensor(xs, [xs.length,1])).dataSync();
```

Comment: Where is xs and ys defined?

Comment: Can you please do `console.log("xt.shape", xt.shape, "yt.shape", yt.shape)` just before `model.fit` and post the result here ?

Comment: @edkeveked xt.shape (3) [1, 251, 1]0: 11: 2512: 1length: 3__proto__: Array(0) yt.shape (2) [251, 1]

Comment: @edkeveked xt.shape (3) [1, 251, 1]  yt.shape (2) [251, 1]

Comment: @scottm, now I see clearly why you have the error. I will update my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to come from `model.fit(x, y)` because there seems to be a mismatch in the shape of x and y.

x has the shape `[1, 251, 1]` and y the shape `[251, 1]`. This does not work because there is more features in x than there is label in y. You have to reshape whether x or y.

- reshape x: `x.reshape([251, 1, 1])` or `x.reshape([251, 1])`

or

- reshape y: `y.reshape([1, 251])` or `y.reshape([1, 251, 1])`

*Note: There is almost an infinite way of reshaping that will work **as long as the first two dimension sizes are equal** and that **the product of all dimension sizes is equal to 251**. What matter in the reshaping is not to loose the correlation between the features and the labels*

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's working now (although the model is very inaccurate lol).